# Pull data from a json file and display it with a button

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to pull data from a json file and display it, but I am unable to proceed with the program because I lack experience in coding Angular.

Currently using Angular 4.3, which uses HttpClientModule.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = '?';
    data;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('/src/app/students.json')

    }

    chgTab1() {
        this.title = "Changed Title";
    }

    chgTab2() {
        //Want to display the items from json file
    }

}
```

**students.json**

```
[
    {"id": "3", "mame": "Dama"},
    {"id": "1", "mame": "ASD"},
    {"id": "2", "mame": "Chris"},
    {"id": "4", "mame": "Sass"},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = '?';
    data;
    showData = false;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {   
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.get('/assets/students.json', { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
})

  }

  chgTab1(){
    this.title ="Changed Title";
  }

  chgTab2(){
    //Want to display the items from json file

    this.showData = !this.showData;
  }

}
```

I have edited the whole thing. It will now work for you. Ensure you have the path to your student.json in the correct place.I moved it to the assets directory

Comment: Is your version angular before 4.0? Because I can't get import Headers from the @angular/common/http for some reason.

Comment: My bad. I have updated the imports. You can remove the common part. Also import rxjs

Comment: Also ensure you import the HttpModule in your app.module.ts.

Comment: Update: I can't get the json file.
GET http://localhost:4200/src/app/students.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: No worries. I have just fired up the computer and tested it out for you. I have changed the answer above and I can confirm it returns the data. Any more problems let me know.

Comment: Finally to show the data in your view. Add <div *ngIf=“data”>{{ data }} </div>

Comment: Thank you dude. Managed to get the data.

Comment: Anytime. Good luck.

Comment: Could you explain the <div *ngIf=“data”>{{ data }} </div>
on how it works?

Comment: Sure. Just an angular if statement. So basically if there is data in the variable, ie what we populate with the http.get(...), it will show he data if not it will not. You could try without the ngIf but I have had errors before where it loads the data before it is populated. Does that make sense. Back on the phone lol.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you. I'm still facing a bit of issue for displaying the data sadly, but I know the code is correct.

Comment: What issue are you facing. I guess you want to iterate over each student and display them?

Comment: Yes. I would like to iterate over each student and display them. I apologize for my inexperience in this programming.

Comment: I'm not too sure on how to solve this problem.
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [“] at column 1 in expression [“data”] at column 2 in [“data”] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:7 ("
  <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf=“data”>{{ data }} </div>
  "):

Comment: You can use an ngFor loop. <div *ngFor=“let student of data”> {{ student }} </div>

Comment: Nevermind solved it. It was a typo in my code. I APOLOGIZE FOR THE INCONVENIENCE CAUSED.

Comment: Yes I got it to work. Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for helping man.